# Imagebutton does not become invisible after translate animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button

I am moving an image button from left to right at the bottom of screen using xml using this:

```
   <translate android:fromXDelta="-500%" android:toXDelta="0%"
   android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="00%"
   android:duration="800"
   android:zAdjustment="bottom"/>
```

At the same time I have a linear layout invisible which by clicking the button becomes visible but my button is still visible.

```
 case R.id.fab_image_button:
            txtTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fabImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            lOUT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 break;
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We need to put the imagebutton in a separate layout and make the whole layout invisible after clicking